# VueJS AXIOS - Is it correct to create an axios instance for every single request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, vue.js, axios

I've built a **VueJS** application that uses **Vue-Axios** to communicate with a Laravel API.

In my project, I have an api.js file that contains the following code:

```js
import axios from "axios";

export function apiRequestProtocol(token = null) {
    var api_instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/",
    });

    if (token) {
        api_instance.interceptors.request.use(
            (config) => {
              config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
              return config;
            },
            (error) => {
              return Promise.reject(error);
            }
        );
    } 
    return api_instance;
}
```

The `apiRequireProtocol` function is imported in every Vue Component that needs to make a request to the Laravel API.

As you can see, every time a component uses `apiRequestProtocol()`, a new Axios instance is created.

I made this in this way because some "requests" from Axios needs `access_token`, and others don't.

I had tried using the same Axios instance for every single request just changing its header, but I couldn't do it successfully. If you know **how to use only one instance changing it depending on the request (if needs token or don't)**, please let me know how.

Furthermore, I would like to know **if I should "delete" these instances** after using them or if there is even a better way to do this.

Thank you!

My package.json:

```json
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@vueuse/head": "^0.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-axios": "^3.2.5",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: "Is it correct to create an axios instance for every single request?" - no. "I had tried using the same Axios instance for every single request just changing its header, but I couldn't do it successfully" - consider reasking the question with your unsuccessful attempt. Currently you have XY problem.

Comment: when using axios server side in next.js having one axios instance with interceptors results in many problem for me most likely resulting from race condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Multiple instances

No you definitely don't want an axios instance for every connection!  But you might want multiple instances.  Specifically, I would use plain `axios.get` for unauthenticated requests, and an instance for every different token in the app.  That way I don't have to mess around with adding and removing interceptors.

### Plain axios requests with headers

Can be done without anything fancy at all:

```js
axios.get(URL, {headers: {"X-my-custom-header": "my-custom-val"}})
```

### Token Authentication with different headers

can be done the same way:

```js
var token_axios = axios.create({ BaseURL: "http://exam.pl" })
var token_interceptor = token_axios.intercepters.request.use(
  config => {
    config.headers.Authorization = "Token: MYTOKEN"
    return config
  },
  error => {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
)
token_axios.get(url, {headers: {"x-my-custom-header": "abc"}})
```

### Overriding Token

can be done exactly the same we we set it originally, and

### removing interceptor

can be done if we create or get a reference to it first:

```js
token_axios.interceptors.request.eject(token_interceptor)
```

(note we saved the reference from above).

Whilst you *could* use the use/eject paradigm to modify one instance every time, and this would be the right approach if tokens changed frequently and requests were rare, if (as I suspect) tokens change infrequently and requests are common, I would simply use a few objects as described above.

To answer your other question, whilst JS has garbage collection, if you *were* creating dozens of throwaway objects, deleting them manually is good practice as the garbage collector causes unpredictable slowdowns when it is called.

### References

https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors

Comment: Thank you, it became much more clear for me

Comment: good!  I recently learned axios myself, so I'm largely answering to get things straight in my own head...  these things can be oddly confusing when new. Feel free to accept if it answers the question.

Comment: What should I do if I have access of token at the component level only?
current implimentation
```function getAxiosInstance(token: string) {
  const axiosInstance = axios.create();
  axiosInstance.defaults.timeout = 25000;
  axiosInstance.defaults.baseURL = Capacitor.isNativePlatform()
    ? import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL_FOR_CAPACITOR
    : import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL;
  axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  return axiosInstance;
}```

Comment: @Homocodian that's probably a separate question, but it sounds like a general state management problem.  If you have state at some high level and need it lower down, you either pass it in or put it in some third place both levels can access.  (Dependency injection is an automatic form of this approach masquerading as the first).

Comment: Thanks, indeed it was a state management issue solved it with zustand, zustand allows to have reactive state as well as non-reactive and can be accessed anywhere with few caveats.